# grep pattern match with multiple variables

Tags: regex, grep

I have been searching around for over an hour and I am not quite finding what I am looking for. I am trying to perform a grep match to make sure the syntax in a command is correct before proceeding.

Contents of file:

```
deploy type:apptype1 artifact:coolio version:1.1.1 in dev
```

What I am looking for is to allow multiple types, artifact, version and allow for only dev or qa. Any other text added or missing should fail.

What I have tried so far is:

```
grep -ie "deploy type:apptype1\|apptype2\|apptype3 artifact:.*version:.*in dev\|qa file
```

The problem is if I add additional text or even change "in" to "on" it still matches. I suspect it is only matching the first part and not the entire line like I am wanting?

Comment: You need parens around the \| statements.... as-is, your regex will match lines with 'apptype2' or 'qa' all by themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

```sh
echo "deploy type:apptype2 artifact:coolio version:1.1.1 in dev" | grep -i -E "deploy type:(apptype1|apptype2|apptype3) artifact:.*version:.*in (dev|qa)"
```

Note the `>` color on the next line indicating previous command returned `0` (Green) or else non zero (Red)

[image: vaidatingByExitCode]

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU `grep`:

```
grep -P '^deploy type:(apptype1|apptype2|apptype3) artifact:.*version:.*in (dev|qa)$' in_file
```

Example:

```
cat > in_file <<EOF
deploy type:apptype1 artifact:coolio version:1.1.1 in dev
deploy type:apptype2 artifact:coolio version:1.1.1 in qa
deploy type:apptype1 artifact:coolio version:1.1.1 on dev
EOF

grep -P '^deploy type:(apptype1|apptype2|apptype3) artifact:.*version:.*in (dev|qa)$' in_file
```

Output:

```
deploy type:apptype1 artifact:coolio version:1.1.1 in dev
deploy type:apptype2 artifact:coolio version:1.1.1 in qa
```

Here, GNU [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) uses option:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.

`^` : Beginning of the line.
`$` : End of the line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, here is a solution for BSD/GNU grep:

```
grep -ie "deploy type:apptype[123] artifact:[[:alnum:]].* version:[[:alnum:]].* in [(dev\|qa)]" file
```

### Edit

@timur-shtatland's answer is better - my answer will not exclude "dev_test" or "qa_temp"